# Настройки времени в зависимости от локали& Swift

Tags: ios, swift, время, uitextfield, datetimepicker

Создал программно  Picker для времени  через textField. Пытаюсь выставить 12 или 24 формат в зависимости от  настроек телефона. 
Если в пикере показывает 12 часовой формат, то в textField , отображаеться 24.

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно настроить это .
Вот код, который сейчас есть.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        timeTextFieldOutlet.inputView = datePicker

        createToolBar()
        let localID = Locale.preferredLanguages.first
        datePicker.locale = Locale(identifier: localID!)



    }

    var datePicker:UIDatePicker =
    {

        let picker = UIDatePicker()

        picker.datePickerMode = .time
        picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerChanged(_sender:)), for: .valueChanged)        

picker.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
       picker.locale = Locale.autoupdatingCurrent


        return picker
    }()
 func getDateFormaPicker()
    {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()

        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        timeTextFieldOutlet.text = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Для форматирования времени согласно локали и в 12/24-часовом формате нужно указать локаль (в противном случае используется системная) и формат вывода времени `timeStyle`

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
var comps = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: Date())
comps.hour = 22
comps.minute = 55

if let date = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent.date(from: comps) {
//    formatter.amSymbol = "" // если нужно убрать AM
//    formatter.pmSymbol = "" // если нужно убрать PM
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
    formatter.timeStyle = .short
    print(formatter.string(from: date))
    formatter.timeStyle = .medium
    print(formatter.string(from: date))
    formatter.timeStyle = .long
    print(formatter.string(from: date))

    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ru_RU")
    formatter.timeStyle = .short
    print(formatter.string(from: date))
    formatter.timeStyle = .medium
    print(formatter.string(from: date))
    formatter.timeStyle = .long
    print(formatter.string(from: date))
}
```

Вывод

> 10:55 PM
>
> 10:55:00 PM
>
> 10:55:00 PM GMT+3
>
> 22:55
>
> 22:55:00
>
> 22:55:00 GMT+3